Why automapper throws stackoverflow exception when using IValueResolver?
Did I use IValueResolver incorrectly?
Actually there should have been some instance reuse logic before the context.Mapper.Map call, what I want to do is to map A instance into AModel instance using custom IValueResolver and handle the circular reference correctly.
open github issue
using AutoMapper;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        a.B = b;
        b.List.Add(a);

        var mapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.AddProfile<Profile1>(); }));

        var model = mapper.Map<AModel>(a);
    }
}

class A
{
    public B B { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public List<A> List { get; set; }

    public B()
    {
        List = new List<A>();
    }
}

class AModel
{
    public BModel B { get; set; }
}

class BModel
{
    public List<AModel> List { get; set; }
}

class Profile1 : Profile
{
    public Profile1()
    {
        CreateMap<A, AModel>().ForMember(x => x.B, o => o.MapFrom<ValueResolver1>());
        CreateMap<B, BModel>();
    }
}

class ValueResolver1 : IValueResolver<A, AModel, BModel>
{
    public BModel Resolve(A source, AModel destination, BModel destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // some custom logic here
        return context.Mapper.Map<BModel>(source.B);
    }
}


Remove the .ForMember(...) from CreateMap<A, AModel>(), as AutoMapper will perform mapping when both properties have the same name. And I don't see any reason that why you need to create the circular reference.

@YongShun It is just sample code, I do need ForMember because I need some logic in Resolve method.

AutoMapper will handle circular reference automatically, but it is your code that tells AutoMapper to resolve mapping endlessly. If you try to rewrite your mapping without AutoMapper you will end up with something like this:
private static AModel MapA(A a)
{
    return new AModel
    {
        B = MapB(a.B),
    };
}

private static BModel MapB(B b)
{
    return new BModel
    {
        List = b.List.Select(a => MapA(a)).ToList(),
    };
}

Can you see how MapA() calls MapB() which then calls back MapA()? It is a recursion and if your customization creates such dependency, AutoMapper will not know how to solve it on its own. Either rewrite your mapper configuration or move the problematic code outside the mapping process.

you can run that sample above, actually there is no such dependency.

Unless the A is empty or does not contain circular references, then no, you can't. Using your sample where you showed how you create A instance, code above will throw StackOverflowException.
